How to retrieve Stake Pool Address using Token Address
How I can find out the Stake Pool address using a token address (ideally using JavaScript)? I know there's a spl-single-pool package (https://spl.solana.com/single-pool) it requires the pool address as an input in several cases but doesn't show a way to retrieve it for a specific token.
For example:
Token Address: bSo13r4TkiE4KumL71LsHTPpL2euBYLFx6h9HP3piy1
Stake Pool Address: stk9ApL5HeVAwPLr3TLhDXdZS8ptVu7zp6ov8HFDuMi

You'll need to fetch all of the stake pools and see which one has the given token address as the token mint, ie:
$ spl-stake-pool list-all

And then for each one:
$ spl-stake-pool list FrdgmWAkRHcCn67eg63Z8ncmFoLNeJhjVVKRzkM5Fw6h
Stake Pool: FrdgmWAkRHcCn67eg63Z8ncmFoLNeJhjVVKRzkM5Fw6h
Validator List: C9kAhBfN4JgfCCW5aS9Uc8YRhNzW2thAWYkqBzfZwpxS
Pool Token Mint: 5Q3nt8x2KByoEgsvnuwXN721TujzYuVyydXVrDqtY4Mc
Epoch Fee: 1/100 of epoch rewards
Stake Withdrawal Fee: 2/100 of withdrawal amount
SOL Withdrawal Fee: 2/100 of withdrawal amount
Stake Deposit Fee: 3/100 of deposit amount
SOL Deposit Fee: 3/100 of deposit amount
Stake Deposit Referral Fee: 0% of Stake Deposit Fee
SOL Deposit Referral Fee: 0% of SOL Deposit Fee

